# python install lxml on mac os 10.10.1

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scrapy, lxml

I bought a new macbook and I am so new to mac os. However, I read a lot on internet about how to install scrap

I did everything, but i have a problem with installing lxml

I tried this on terminal

```
pip install lxml
```

and a lot of stuff started to be downloading and many text was written on the terminal, but i got this error message on red in the terminal

```
1 error generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/rd/fxgsy46j3l77f6l9h_hv2fjm0000gn/T/pip_build_mycomputername/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/rd/fxgsy46j3l77f6l9h_hv2fjm0000gn/T/pip-WvDTPQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rd/fxgsy46j3l77f6l9h_hv2fjm0000gn/T/pip_build_mycomputername/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/mycomputername/.pip/pip.log
```

and now when I call scrapy spider that words with lxml, i got this error message

```
ImportError: No module named lxml.html
```

what should I do please?

any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question. you can find your ans [here][1].
This might also [help][2].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666578/how-do-i-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4-i-have-exhausted-all-options

Comment: @DarKnight the link you provided states that i have to go to Xcode then preferences then download and download the command line tools. However, i went there and there wasn't command line tools. there was just some updates for the os and some iOS simulators to install

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had that problem, and what I did is:

installed all xcode (2.8GB) from apple store.

to be sure that the installation is successfully finished: open terminal and typed

```
xcode-select -p
```

you should get something like this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

now you need to install command line tools. try to type `gcc` on the terminal, then there are two possibilities: either you get a window asking to install the tools and you have to click on `install`, or you will get an error message.

if you get an error message, then don't worry just try to install the tools using this command `xcode-select --install`

after that restart the mac and then re install lxml again like this :

```
pip install lxml
```

then try to run scrapy again

if you encounter any other error on any other library, easily just reinstall scrapy using **easy_install** and **NOT** using pip

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you did not re-install the Command Line Tools after upgrading.

Usually XCode should be upgraded to the latest version (4.4) (I believe when I updated to 10.8 I also updated a whole bunch of other applications, including XCode). After the update you need to re-install the Command Line Tools. This can now be done via a setting in XCode:

Go to "Preferences -> Downloads" and install "Command Line Tools".

Comment: why you talking about xcdoe? i have never upgraded the Xcode or the mac os. i bought the mac just a week ago and installed Xcode.

Comment: i went there and there wasn't command line tools. there was just some updates for the os and some iOS simulators to install