# MacSierra broken the installation of psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am unable to install `psycopg2` using python2.7 or python 3.4. I tried installing these ways:

- `pip install psycopg2`
- `python setup.py install` on psycopg2 download file

  The error:

  ld: library not found for -lssl
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

I installed Postgres with `brew` and had no problem until I upgraded Mac to Sierra. I looked online but this fails:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/ pip install psycopg2
```

I managed to have a system package for psycopg2, but I want to be able to install psycopg2 using pip. What else can I do ?

Comment: Have you installed Xcode?

Comment: @PhilipTzou, yes, currently on version 8.1

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30428349/2644759

Comment: That was it, thanks ! I am sure I had gcc before.

Comment: Well [`clang`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) is compatible with `gcc` but is not `gcc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python install lxml on mac os 10.10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410030/python-install-lxml-on-mac-os-10-10-1)